# Windows 8 disable Modern-UI options bar animation

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

The option menu at the bottom of the Windows-8 Modern-Ui is sliding in with a nice animation (i.e. right-click on an application). **How can I completely disable this animation?** and make the bar appear instantly.

Comment: try to disable the animation in the desktop control panel: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127261-animate-windows-when-minimizing-maximizing.html Maybe this also disables the "Metro" animation.

Comment: No - I've already disabled that. Does not influence Metro/Modern-Ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a recent Windows Update solved the issue when you disable the `Animate controls and elements inside windows` option.

1. Open the `System` in the Control Panel and click `Advanced system settings`
2. In the `Performance` tab open the Performance Settings
3. Now disable the `Animate controls and elements inside windows`

[image]